# Вывод кнопок "ya-share2" в modx revo на конкретный продукт в minishop

Tags: modx, ya-share2

Друзья, такой вопрос, запутался совсем.. яндексовы кнопки поделиться отлично работают на отдельной странице, но как их прикрепить к выводу каждого отдельного товара? Со страницы товаров? Типа - поделиться - кот вася - фото и ссыла на страницу. Поделиться  - кошка Клава - фото и ссыла на страницу.
Вывод такой пока:

```
<p>Рассказать друзьям:</p> 
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script> 
<div class="ya-share2"

data-url="[[+data-url]]"
data-title="[[+pagetitle]]"
data-image="[[+tv.news_image?]]"
data-size ="s" 
data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus,twitter,lj,telegram"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

решение получилось такое: скрипты от яндекса - в шаблон, в вызов чанка - такую конструкцию:

```
<div class="ya-share2"
data-url="[[++site_url]]/[[~[[*id]]]][[+alias]].html"
data-title="[[+pagetitle]]"
data-image="[[+tv.news_image?]]"
data-size ="s" 
data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus,twitter,lj,telegram"></div>
```